# How to remove gap

Tags: css, html

I have a simple layout in my web page

```
<body >
<div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="Images/home.jpg" style="width:100%;" />
        </div>      
 </div>
</body>
```

and my style sheet content is

```
body, html{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#page
{
    position:relative;    
    width: 960px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #222 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #222 0px 0px 8px;
    box-shadow: #222 0px 0px 8px;    
    background:url('../../Images/headbg960.jpg');
}

#header{
    padding:30px 90px 0px 90px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

I cannot figure out why there is a 5px gap between the bottom of the image and the bottom edge of the header.  Any trick in css produce this?  How can I fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline element such a images are subject to `whitespace`

Make the image `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can something be solved by applying `display: block` on the image.  So in your stylesheet you will need to add

```
#header img {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to your image's CSS: `style="width:100%;vertical-align:top;"`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sLkdeyns/)**